# How do I filter a list of 100 stop words from a RegExp?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a product search demo that filter items based on search words.

As you type the textbox dynamically matches the search query against keywords inside label tags. If all the keywords match, the parent div stays visible. If keywords are missing, the div fades away.

I'm trying to add a list of stopwords so I can filter common phrase constructs. Ideally, they would be called by a stopword.js or .txt. (it is a demo and needs to work offline)

The reason for this is I want all the boxes to be visible when the query is empty, and progressively fade away only when a new keyword does not match.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eqn5h7vk/

Code:

```js
$("#search-input").keyup(function(){
  // Retrieve the input field text and reset the count to zero
  var filter = $(this).val(), count = 0; 
 

  // Loop through the word list
  $(".content_boxes div").each(function(){
      var pattern = filter.trim().match(/[a-zA-Z]+|[0-9]+/g) || "";  // null coalescing: "" if null
      if(pattern) {
        pattern = pattern.map(function(el) { 
          return '(?=.*' + el + ')';
        });

        //join if there is something in the array
        pattern = pattern.join("");
     }

     //console.log(pattern.join("")); 
     // If the word list does not contain the text phrase, fade it out

     if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(pattern, "i")) < 0) {
          $(this).fadeOut("slow");


      // Show the product divs  if the phrase matches and increase the count by 1
      } else {
          $(this).show();
          count++;
      }
  });

  // Update the count
  var numberItems = count;
  $("#filter-count").text("Number of Comments = "+count);
  });
```

```css
body {font-family:arial}

input {font-size:20px; border:1px solid #cecece; padding:5px; border-radius:5px; width:300px;}


b {color:blue}


label {display:none}

.content {width:100px; margin:5px; background:#cecece; float: left; border-radius:5px; padding:10px; text-align:center}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="search-input" type="text" Placeholder="Search fruit by color">



<p>Boxes will show up if keywords <b>Red</b>, <b>Green</b> or <b>Yellow</b> match the label</p>

<p>Im trying to add a list of stopwords so if you search for <b>"Show me yellow and green fruits"</b>, the keywords <b>show</b>, <b>me</b>, <b>and</b>, <b>fruits</b> are ignored by the search.




<div class="content_boxes">
  
  <div class="content"><label>Red green</label><span>Apple</span></div>
  <div class="content"><label>yellow</label><span>Banana</span></div>
  <div class="content"><label>Red</label><span>Cherry</span></div>
  <div class="content"><label>green red</label><span>Grapes</span></div>
  <div class="content"><label>green</label><span>Kiwi</span></div>
  <div class="content"><label>yellow</label><span>Lemon</span></div>
  <div class="content"><label>green</label><span>Lime</span></div>
  <div class="content"><label>green yellow</label><span>Pears</span></div>
  <div class="content"><label>Red</label><span>Strawberry</span></div>
  <div class="content"><label>red green</label><span>Watermelon</span></div>
```

Comment: what does a "stopword" mean?

Comment: Common words that are ignored on a search. More details: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words